# Get something out of string c#

Tags: c#

So I need to get a part of a string, that contains: name=

The string looks like this:
[Zone] ZoneChangeList.ProcessChanges() - id=1 local=False [name=XXX id=4 zone=PLAY zonePos=0 cardId=HERO_01 player=1] zone from  -> FRIENDLY PLAY (Hero)

Where XXX can be any length and including spaces and everything else than that should be replaced with nothing.

Any ideas??

Regards!

Comment: Is this one long string or there are newlines inside? In other words, do you get this string reading from a file?

Comment: what happens if XXX is `My name is id=4`? How do you know when the name field ends and others begin?

Comment: XXX can never be id=, in my situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are absolutely sure that `id` comes immediately after `name`, you can use a RegEx pattern like this:

`\[name=(?<NameGroup>(.*))\s*id`

When you do a match, `NameGroup` will contain the name (in this case, xxx). You can then do [Regex.Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx) using this pattern to replace the name with something else. You might need to play around with the pattern based on your needs to make sure it captures all  corner cases.

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.IndexOf` to find the index of the "name=" tag and the index of the "id=" tag then substring between those indices. You will have to account for the length of the tags but that shouldn't be an issue since the lengths of those tags are known

```
string s = "[Zone] ZoneChangeList.ProcessChanges() - id=1 local=False [name=XXX id=4 zone=PLAY zonePos=0 cardId=HERO_01 player=1] zone from -> FRIENDLY PLAY (Hero)"
int x = s.IndexOf("[name=") + "name=".Length;
int y = s.IndexOf(" id=");
s.Substring(x,y);
```

Comment: `IndexOf` gives you the index where the substring begins or -1 if it is not found.

Answer (score 1):

```
    string tag = "[name=";
    string name = str.Split(' ').Single(x => string.Concat(x.Take(tag.Length)) == tag).Remove(0, tag.Length);
```

Assumes the data will always be space separated, gets the element that starts with the correct tag (assumes this to be unique) and then trims of the tag and returns the name data.

Comment: `x.Take(6)` will return a `IEnumerable<char>` which you cannot compare to a `string` with the `==` operator.  Use `x.Substring(0,6)` instead or `new string(x.Take(6).ToArray())`.